# Module not returning echoing or printing variable

Tags: debugging

I'm writing a module to change a user's shopping cart order ID based on a stored value from their profile, which cannot be edited from the users.

In the hook call to `commerce_cart_order_id` I tried the following code, but it doesn't change the order ID. Printing `$orderidentifier` with `krumo()` shows `1`; if I change `return $orderidentifier;` with `return 1;`  my cart changes just as I'd expect it to.

```
global $user;
$user_full = user_load($user->uid);
$orderidentifier = $user_full->field_currentcartorder['und'][0]['value'];
return $orderidentifier;
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: if `return 1;` works then it simply means `$user_full->field_currentcartorder['und'][0]['value']` is empty (or there's other code involved that we can't see). I guess there's an outside change casting to an `int` would make a difference, but I think it's unlikely

Comment: if I print it with krumo() it says it's equal to 1

Comment: Then your argument is with PHP :) Variable assignment is understandably a cornerstone of the language - standard PHP can't do anything to change `$orderidentifier` between two sequential lines of code. Definitely not in the way your code describes anyway

Comment: when printed with krumo and getting 1 I would expect the next line returning the same variable to return 1 as well however it seems to be null on the return which of course makes no sense as I just had a value in the previous line and did nothing to change it

Comment: also I tried to echoing and printing it and got no results however printing or echoing <br /> tags causes breaks to appear at the top of the page

Comment: Unless you see '1' when you print, it means `$user_full->field_currentcartorder['und'][0]['value']` is empty (as far as PHP is concerned, at least, can't comment about it from any other angle)

Comment: Are you sure there aren't other calls to `krumo()` that are outputting that `1` you see? As @Clive said, PHP doesn't change a local variables automagically. Also, it is a bad idea to access a field value like that; there are functions for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed it I had to add an `$orderidentifier = intval($orderidentifier);` to convert it to an integer so the hook I was calling could understand it

Comment: Indeed: `if (!empty($order_id) && is_int($order_id)) {` is in `commerce_cart_order_id()`. So it wants to enforce an integer. In a codebase and language that have severe type-safety problems. Interesting approach